# Merge lists and pick properties from both

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. `List<A>`, where the type `A` has two properties { x, y } and `List<B>` where the type `B` has two properties { y, z }.

I want to join the two lists on y and then pick x and z in my new list.

Is this possible using some a LINQ one-liner?

Comment: does y always have the same index location?

Comment: There are some fundamental questions that need answered before this can be solved. For example, what if multiple items exist for a particular value of `y`? And: What if only one of the two lists contains an entry for a particular value of `y`? What value would be used for the missing `x` or `z` data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have two types:

```
class A
{
   public int x {get; set;}
   public int y {get; set;}
}
    
class B
{
   public int y {get;set;}
   public int z {get;set;}
}
```

And your two lists:

```
List<A> a = new List<A> { new A { x = 1, y = 2 }, new A { x= 2, y = 3}};
List<B> b = new List<B> { new B { y = 2, z = 2 }, new B { y= 3, z = 3}};
```

You can join them with LINQ:

```
var joined = a.Join(b, a => a.y, b => b.y, (a,b) => new {a.x, b.z}).ToList();
```

You will have a List with two items: x=1, z=2 and x=2, z=3.

Comment: Great! This was exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for linq [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0)

```
int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

foreach (int num in union)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", num);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 5 3 9 7 8 6 4 1 0
*/
```

Your case [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKVUSv):

```
string[] ints1 = { "x", "y" };
string[] ints2 = { "y", "Z" };

IEnumerable<string> union = ints1.Union(ints2);

foreach (string num in union)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", num);
}
```

Comment: Very good example. It shows that a `Union` is a `Concat().Distinct()`

Comment: Ok I realize I wasn't clear enough. So what I have is two list were the properties is X and Y  or Y and Z. So the value of them is different and there is loads of values in each list. 
So I need to join the values of the properties Y

Comment: I still don't understand the case. Can you please provide the example in your question? Objects have properties, lists have items.

Comment: OP is asking for a **single** list containing instances of **different** types.

Comment: Ok, it didn't look like that at all to me. I got it from the accepted answer.